# Is the lane bots don't play predetermined?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was playing a beginner bot game to get my win of the day bonus and one of the other players disconnected during loading. I went solo top and only one bot came instead of the normal two, the other bot did not show up before far into the game when the disconnected player came back.

So do the bots look at where the missing player should have been (looking at a standard 2-1-2 lane distribution) or is it always top lane that will receive one less bot if a player disconnects at start?

Also a side note, the missing player received xp while he was gone so he was level 5 by the time he was back, the bot did not and was level 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a player disconnects the top lane will go down to one computer player to even out the teams.  If 2 disconnect it will stay the same (only compensates for one character).  As for the levels I have noticed that sometimes they level sometimes they do not, my theory is turrets grant xp bonus but I have never sat down and really tried to figure it out as I am usually playing when we are a player down :p

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are. support is bot and so on